# Send data from WPF to Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, wpf, socket.io

There is this code on WPF in which I first receive data from Flutter and there is also where it is being sent. I get the data from Flutter perfectly

```
private async Task ShowInitialWindowStateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        socket.EmitAsync("restart-timer", new { uid = UidClient });
       

        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        this.HideToTray();
        answerStackPanel.Children.Clear();
        textBlock.Text = "";
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        UnlockKeyboard();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Next I have to get it on the server, here is the provided code

```
socket.on('restart-timer', ({ uid: targetUid }) => {
    // Проверяем, существует ли комната с указанным UID
    if (!io.sockets.adapter.rooms.has(targetUid)) {
        socket.emit('error', 'UID not found');
        return;
    }

    console.log('RestartTimer: ' + targetUid);

    if (socket.uid !== targetUid) {

      io.to(targetUid).emit('restart-timer', { uid: targetUid });
    }
  });
```

And then there should be getting them into Flutter

```
widget.socket.on('restart-timer', (data) {
      print('Получены данные о перезапуске таймера: $data');
      restartTimer();
    });
```

For some reason, he does not want to restart the timer after receiving this command

I tried using socket.emit and io.sockets.in